# constraint a type to have properties of a specific type

Tags: typescript

```
interface Person {id:number, name:string}


const someFunction(people: ???) => {...}
```

Question: Is it possible to typeguard people parameter to only accept an object with all properties as a Person. Such as:

```
people:{
   user1:{id:1,name:'user1'},
   user2:{id:1,name:'user2'},
   user3:{id:1,name:'user3'}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question a custom type with a dynamic key might be useful

```
interface Person {id:number, name:string}

type People = {
    [key:string]:Person;
}

const someFunction = (people:People ) => {...}

someFunction({"user1":{id:1,name:"name1"},"user2":{id:1,name:"name2"}})
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Record<Keys,Type>

You can leverage **[Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)** with `string` as key's type and `Person` as value's type.

```js
interface Person {
  id: number,
  name: string,
}

const someFunction = (people: Record<string, Person>) => {
  // function logic here
};

someFunction({
  user1: { id: 1, name: 'user1' },
  user2: { id: 1, name: 'user2' },
  user3: { id: 1, name: 'user3' },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [index signatures](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures):

```
interface Person {id:number, name:string}

const someFunction = (people: { [index:string]: Person }) => { /* ... */ }

someFunction({
   user1:{id:1,name:'user1'},
   user2:{id:1,name:'user2'},
   user3:{id:1,name:'user3'}
});
```